# Material-UI Box component alignment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Can someone please help me to understand why does alignment between `Typography` and `IconButton` doesn't work properly in my situation? The `IconButton` is lower then `Typography`?
[image]

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-dubinsky-mwtzp?file=/src/demo.js

Comment: Thank you for providing the sandbox, but please note that you need to edit App.js to actually display an `OrderCard`. Currently, you left the default template file in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the css for those elements. The `Typography` has `margin-bottom: 0.35em` because you passed it `gutterBottom`, and the containing `Box` is using `display: flex` and `align-content: center`. I think you probably meant to *not* use `gutterBottom` and to use `align-items: center` on the `Box` instead.

Regarding the confusion between `align-content` and `align-items`, [this](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#section-align-content) is an excellent `flexbox` cheatsheet that you can reference. It notes:

> Note, this [align-content] property has no effect on a single-line flex container.

By which it means containers with `flex-wrap: nowrap`, which is the [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).